# Importing multiple class files in Java

Tags: java, file, import

I am trying to program a game engine in which users would be able to create multiple "level files." However, since the user would be able to make as many levels as they wanted, there's no set amount of levels or set names. I'm not really sure how to import the files in to the engine. I've tried assigning the files to an array but that didn't work well, as it couldn't find any of the methods that way. Currently I have the level files as java files with a method that sets the variables and sets any cutscene text there may be.

Comment: I don't think you're approaching this the right way, but if you want to import all files in a package, you can just do something like `java.util.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing Data about user created levels within Java files, a better way to go about this would be to write a Level class which takes input from an external file such as a .txt file.

For example the user can create a file called "firstlevel.txt" and add it to the levels folder which would be able to be read by your Level class.

More specifically your constructor could be something like

```
Level startingLevel = new Level("startinglvl.txt");
```

which you could then add to an array of levels

```
Level[] levels = new Level[64];
```

and then just add to the array when the game needs to load a user generated level.

Comment: mostly serialization is used for games. Save the whole objects.

Comment: @bgth Wouldn't that still require an object to parse through the serialized files?

Comment: Yeah.. right. your way will work for this case. But in the correct way for creating games, there should be a Level class with the details about the current level the user is on and the state of other objects which make the class separately for each user. So, when user comes and starts his game, the particular Level class is loaded and the other related files are loaded to come back to the last state the game was on.

Comment: Can't argue with that.

Comment: If You think about dynamically add CODE (not data), since Java 7 is possible to dynamically compile javax.tools.ToolProvidergetSystemJavaCompiler(); 

 user class Level7 can override from GeneralLevel etc.